# Magento - Session expired. Try to relogin

Tags: magento

I'm trying to make an authentication to get some data from a client in Magento. I have valid access to do so, but always I am receiving the response "Session expired. Try to relogin". I am using both Advanced Rest Client with Chrome and 
Rest Client with Mozila. I made a lot of requests to change my Token but the message is always the same.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:Magento">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:call soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
         <sessionid xsi:type="xsd:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</sessionid><resourcepath xsi:type="xsd:string">mobile.login</resourcepath><args soap-enc:arraytype="ns2:Map[1]" xsi:type="SOAP-ENC:Array"><item xsi:type="ns2:Map"><item><key xsi:type="xsd:string">email</key><value xsi:type="xsd:string">everton.com.br</value></item><item><key xsi:type="xsd:string">senha</key><value xsi:type="xsd:string">teste123</value></item></item></args>
      </urn:call>
   </soapenv:Body>    
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Thanks for help!!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like we way you specify your `sessionId` is incorrect.

It should be

```
 <sessionId xsi:type="xsd:string">xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</sessionId>
```